# R: write csv in unicode, need actual text

Tags: r, unicode, web-scraping

I have the following R script for scraping some textual data from a website.

```
library('rvest')

term_data_final <- c()
defn_data_final <- c()

for (term in 1:10) {    

    url_base <- 'http://www.nplg.gov.ge/gwdict/index.php?a=term&d=9&t='
    url <- paste(url_base, term, sep="")

    webpage <- read_html(url)

    term_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage, '.term')
    term_data <- html_text(term_data_html)

    if (!grepl("\\?", term_data)) {
        term_data_final <- c(term_data_final, term_data)

        defn_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage, '.defnblock')
        defn_data <- html_text(defn_data_html)

        defn_data_final <- c(defn_data_final, defn_data)
    }   
}

RusGeoDict <- data.frame(term_data_final, defn_data_final)
write.csv(RusGeoDict, file = 'RusGeoDict.csv', fileEncoding="UTF-8")
```

The script combines the scraped data into a dataframe and then writes that dataframe to a csv file. The scraped text is in Russian and Georgian characters and when saved to a dataframe and a csv, instead of text I get hexadecimal unicode of the format: . When I output the lists that are created before being combined into a dataframe, such as `term_data_final` I get the original text, but once I save to a dataframe and output to a csv file I get unicode. Is there any way to get the original text in Georgian and Russian characters saved to a csv without the unicode output. Thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce this, but I think it's because I'm on macOS, which handles locales well. (Linux does too; Windows doesn't.) There's a chance the data saved is correct, but the utility you're using to look at it can't read it, so rule that out first. (If you're in R, `cat` instead of printing.) If it really is `write.csv` causing the problems, try alternatives like `readr::write_csv` or `data.table::fwrite`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't know any Russian, but I think you can just set the GeoDict before you run your script, right.

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "russian")

RusGeoDict <- data.frame(term_data_final, defn_data_final)
```

I just tried it and I think it's working.  I can't really say for sure though.  Try it and feedback with your findings.

Finally, see the link below. for additional ideas.

https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-and-foreign-characters/

Comment: I've tried to set the locale to Russian, but that only changes the structure of the csv file, while the output remains in `<U+0410>` type format, instead of actual characters R outputs strings of character codes. I think this is due to how the `data.frames` command stores or encodes the data. Is there a way to specify encoding for this command in particular?

Comment: @revazsurg: Sounds like you need to share more information about your locale settings and the available fonts. You may not have your console font configured in a manner that can handle Unicode.